# Why is poll() better than select()?

Tags: sockets

It is said select() is not scalable because it needs to go over an array with the size of max num of file describers (FD): complexity O(max_num_FD). And it is said that poll() is better because it only goes over an array with size of num of active FD(): complexity O(num of active FD) what does active FD mean?

Is poll() a popular way used by large scale servers with many available data at a time? Usually which socket approach does a large scale server usually use in reality?

Comment: Is this for a specific language?

Comment: @Edgar It's raw C using raw Unix system calls.

Comment: @SzG No, it's any language using Unix system calls. `select` and `poll` are directly available in a number of languages. The language doesn't matter, the magic performance sauce and the definition of an "active fd" are in the kernel, not in the language.

Comment: You shouldn't use those calls anyway if epoll or kqueue are availabe. Use libevents or boost aio. select and poll are obsolete.

Comment: @@usr, have you heared put_getn, how is it compared with epoll() and kqueue?

Comment: @usr You assume C++. Linux system calls are never obsolete, because Linus Torvalds will preserve backwards compatibility with his own life forever. If anything, you can trust Linux system calls. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant port_getn(), not put_getn().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active FD means an open file descriptor.

Both select() and poll() are for single-threaded single-process programs to allow them to handle multiple connections at the same time. For instance OpenWRT's uhttpd web-server is like that.

select() and poll() are available on all Unices.
The better scaling O(1) versions are `epoll` on Linux and `kqueue` on BSDs. Less portable, though. But you can install `libkqueue0` on Debian Linux.

Many programs use other approaches. For instance sshd, the SSH daemon, spawns a child process for each connection. Others handle each connection in a thread.

Comment: Do you mean using ssh for large scale server? like ssh http connection?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. have u heard put_getn? I heard it is scalable too.How is it compared with epoll() and kqueue?

Comment: Never heard of put_getn(). Google returned nothing useful, nor did `man put_getn`. For details on epoll, just type `man epoll` on a Linux system. kqueue seems to be BSD specific.

Comment: I also heard poll() can be used if a large scale server is single-thread mode (bcz single-thread simplifies design) but with available data in many sockets at any time (e.g. a large web server with very heavy traffic). Is it true?

Comment: I think it's definitely true. select() is the worst-scaling, poll() is better, epoll and kqueue are best, but somewhat less portable.

Comment: Thanks, BTW, the other API I was mentioned is port_getn(), not put_getn().